# In Jquery, how can I make a div smoothly slide down from A to B so that another div fades in A?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried this:

```
$('#hidden_div').fadeIn();
```

But the div that I want to smoothly slide down, just teleports itself to its next position. (I want it to slide smoothly to it)
Then this:

```
$('#sliding_div').animate({marginTop: '+=400px'},1000);
$('#hidden_div').fadeIn();
```

But I didn't get the right effect.
How can you achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sliding_div').animate({marginTop: '+=400px', opacity:1},1000);
```

and before, set #sliding_div opacity to 0

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the effect you're after, you need to `fadeIn()` the second div after the `animate()` has completed. You can use the `callback` parameter of `animate()` to do this:

```
$('#sliding_div').animate(
    { marginTop: '+=400px' },
    1000,
    function() {
        $('#hidden_div').fadeIn();
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for your response. The problem is that a marginTop of 400px is created. So what happens it that: it slides down 400px, then when the hidden div fades in, the sliding_div snaps down another 400px. Maybe something to do with relative positioning? Thanks

Comment: Could you post a http://jsfiddle.net with your code in so I can see what you mean?

Comment: So when the blue div appears, the green snaps down again. Because it has a marginTop of 400px

Comment: I guess I could counteract that by         `$('#sliding_div').animate({marginTop: '-=400px'},0);` but is this a clean enough way of doing it? I'm worried it might not be smooth if the client's computer is slow

Comment: The problem is that the bottom div still has *margin-top: 400px;* applied to it when the other div appears.  Therefore, the bottom div then applies its margin top to the bottom of the top box rather than the top of the page.  Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/W8AtL/5/ (position: absolute; on second div)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a smoother version: http://jsfiddle.net/W8AtL/4/

`This fixes the jump from it being marginTop.`